# Elastic search - Single Daily index vs Multiple Hourly index vs Data Streams

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm currently working on a solution which collects multiple datas from different applications. I want it more optimised for both write and read throughput. I'm going to store these data for a single day and in time based indices.

I want to understand which is better among the both,

1. Currently used approach - ( Single Daily index ) :

   Currently with this approach the shard size is around 30GB (but will increase in the future when the number of applications increases)

   I found a few disadvantages with this approach,

- As the index size grow searching becomes slower, shards reallocation, recovery becomes slower as well
- We're storing 2 daily indices unnecessarily as we need to query across multiple timezones.

2. Alternate approach - (Hourly Index) :

- Searching on multiple smaller indices ( I query a max range of 2hrs data , so 3 indices max) which must be faster .
- Can be helpful when the data size grows.
- Need to store only 25 hourly indices (for querying across multiple timezones) and can delete | rollover the 25th(last) index using ILM and can prevent lot of storage.

3. Alternate approach 2 - (Data streams) :

- I saw from the ES documentation that data streams are useful for logs, events, metrics, and other continuously generated data.
- It rolls over the index automatically based on the index lifecycle policy conditions that you have set.
- Data streams are like aliases with superpowers. The difference is you always write to one index while keep querying on the entire hidden collection of indices.

I'm thinking of choosing an alternate approach as i believe the data size is ought to grow in the future and the current model might not be able to scale up to number of writes and reads .

Which is best approach here?

Comment: you might find useful the new rollover conditions based on size of the indices https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ilm-rollover.html

Comment: Avoid having too many shards (~600 shards per node, ~20k shards per cluster) so ILM based on age + shard size (keep it around 40-50 GB) is your friend, either with manual aliases or data streams.